# How to define more one condition in a While

Tags: vb6, while-loop, logical-operators

I would like something like that :

```
While Not RdoRst.EOF And RdoRst(2) = "Foo"
        cboComboBox.AddItem RdoRst(1)
        cboComboBox.ItemData(cboComboBox.NewIndex) = RdoRst(0)
        RdoRst.MoveNext
Wend
```

I want that the expression 1 (Not RdoRst.EOF) is evaluated first. Then if it returns true, the expression 2 is evaluated too (RdoRst(2) = "Foo"). If expression 1 return false, the expression 2 is not evaluated.

Regards,

Florian

Comment: Always use `Do ... Loop` instead of `While ... Wend`. `Do` loops can be quit with `Exit Do` which will solve your case most easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AndAlso](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817250) is not available in VB6. Try this

```
Do 
  If RdoRst.EOF Then Exit Do 
  If Not RdoRst(2) ="Foo" Then Exit Do      
  cboComboBox.AddItem RdoRst(1)  
  cboComboBox.ItemData(cboComboBox.NewIndex) = RdoRst(0)  
  RdoRst.MoveNext  
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
While Not RdoRst.EOF 
    If RdoRst(2) = "Foo" Then
        cboComboBox.AddItem RdoRst(1) 
        cboComboBox.ItemData(cboComboBox.NewIndex) = RdoRst(0) 
    Else
        Exit Wend
    End If
    RdoRst.MoveNext 
Wend
```

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't your code behave differently from the code in the question? Code in the question stops looping immediately when a non-Foo value is found. Your code keeps on looping in the hopes of finding another Foo.

Answer (score 0):

The question relates to 'short circuit'  evaluation of condition expressions. Well VB6 does not support this feature. I know this is stupid.